# What is the probability of not rolling any given number on 10 rolls of a die?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, permutations, dice

In other words, ALL combinations which don't contain at least one of the number from 1-6 would count.

So for example...

5, 2, 3, 3, 4, 1, 5, 5, 3, 1 would be counted because there is no 6

Also

5, 3, 3, 3, 4, 1, 5, 5, 3, 1 would be counted as well because there is no 2 or 6

I am trying to figure out how many combinations/what percentage of the combinations out of 6^10, contain AT LEAST one missing number from 1-6.

How do I go about figuring this out?

Comment: Use inclusion/exclusion.

Answer (score 2):

The probability of not obtaining a specific result is $\left(\dfrac{5}{6}\right)^{\!10}$, and there are $6$ specific results.

But simply adding them together over counts the events of not obtaining 2 or more specific results.

The probability of not obtaining $k$ specified results is $\left(\dfrac{6-k}{6}\right)^{10}$, and there are $\dbinom{6}{k}$ ways of choosing $k$ specific results.

Now, can you use the **Principle of Inclusion and Exclusion** to put this together?